# Drag and drop cells vertically in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

```
|-----------------|----------------------|   
| 10th of May     | Cleaning kitchen     |  
|-----------------|----------------------|  
| 17th of May     | Cleaning living      |  
|                 | room and the         |
|                 | basement             |  
|-----------------|----------------------|  
| 24 th of May    | Cleaning balcony     |  
|-----------------|----------------------|
```

---

I have two columns.

The items in column two should be draggable vertically to change place with eachother (not more than one item per row/date).

The items in column one should not change position vertically.

What kind of solution should I look into that does the above and as well respects the adjacent cell height?

Comment: jQuery UI's drag and drop would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T6A2B/1/

Using Jquery sortable and connectWith option :

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".draggable"
        }).disableSelection();
});
```